# Continuity of floor function

Tags: calculus, continuity

Am I right in saying that $f(0)=0$ for $f(x)=1/\left(\lfloor 1/x\rfloor\right)$. Is it also true that it is continuous at 0 and $x$'s near $0$?

Comment: I don't know if the limit exists(I would need to investigate it) but $f(0)$ is certainly not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be right if you said $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac 1 {\lfloor 1/x \rfloor} = 0$, and if you defined a function as
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac 1 {\lfloor 1/x \rfloor} & \text{if }x>0, \\[6pt] 0 & \text{ if }x=0, \end{cases}
$$
then that is continuous at $0$.  It's also continuous at some points near $0$, but not all, since it has some jump discontinuities.  And no matter how close you get to $0$, there are some jump discontinuities closer to $0$ than that.